# formatting SQL in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to open an ODBC connection and retrieve data.  I have some SQL queries that populate what I need:

```
SELECT
  tbl.a AS test1
  tbl.b AS test2
  tbl.c AS test3
FROM
  db.tbl AS tbl
INNER JOIN db.more AS more
  ON more.a = tbl.a
```

Is there a way I can input this query in VBA so it retains its structure and looks readable?  I did this:

```
Dim sql AS string
sql = ""
sql = sql & "SELECT"
sql = sql & "  tbl.a AS test1"
sql = sql & "  tbl.b AS test2"
sql = sql & "  tbl.c AS test3"
sql = sql & "FROM"
sql = sql & "  db.tbl AS tbl"
sql = sql & "INNER JOIN db.more AS more"
sql = sql & "  ON more.a = tbl.a"
```

This doesn't really look good to me, buf it's the best I can do then I'll manage.  I just wanted to see if there was a better way.

Comment: Also discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671308/best-way-to-define-a-large-vba-string-i-e-heredoc-equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only preference but maybe this?

```
sql = "SELECT" + _
      "  tbl.a AS test1" + _
      "  tbl.b AS test2" + _
      "  tbl.c AS test3" + _
      "FROM"             + _
      "  db.tbl AS tbl"  + _
      "INNER JOIN db.more AS more" + _
      "  ON more.a = tbl.a"
```

Another option is to enter the SQL into a cell in a worksheet, Then *HIDE* that worksheet, Then in VBA simply use:

```
sql = Worksheet("NameOfHiddenWorkSheet").Range("A1").Value
```

In my needs I usually name the sheets as Settings and Name the Ranges (Range Names)

Then you could call it like:

```
sql = Sheets("Settings").Range("Sql").Value
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  I had considered putting the sql on a worksheet like you said, but there are some fields that are actually dynamic based off some range values so it would be equally choppy across multiple rows so the basic approach is probably easier.  I do like that idea if it was static SQL code though!

Comment: One problem with using line continuation for the assignment of an SQL string is that you can run up against the limit of 25 lines pretty easily.

Comment: Just ran up against this.  I may have to store it after all, or just go with the original method.  How annoying!

Comment: @JeffreyKramer There is also always the option of storing the commands  in a file, either online or in the secure location, or in the registry these options also allow you the ability to modify the connections, and SQL statements without the need to open excel and VBA Editor also. There are dozens of ways to improve on your situation, it really all depends on exactly what you have and want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Does this helps?

```
Sub test()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT " & _
      "tbl.a AS test1 " & _
      "tbl.b AS test2 " & _
      "tbl.c AS test3 " & _
    "FROM " & _
      "db.tbl AS tbl" & _
    "INNER JOIN db.more AS more" & _
      "ON more.a = tbl.a"

End Sub
```