# Run time Error : "String Parameter Too long"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I used the following code in word-VBA. But when I executed it on a selected paragraph, it gives Run-time error-5854 "String parameter too long". It works fine for small paragraphs. Please help.

Code:

```
Sub Count_of_words()
'
' Count Macro
'
'

Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim i As Integer

WrdArray() = Split(Selection, ".") 'Change with ; if required
'MsgBox ("length: " & UBound(WrdArray))

For i = 0 To UBound(WrdArray)

    If (Number_of_Words(WrdArray(i))) > "20" Then

        '****Set search parameters***************

        Selection.Find.Text = WrdArray(i)
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        Selection.Select
        Selection.MoveRight wdCharacter, Len(WrdArray(i)) + 1, True
        Selection.Range.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        '****************************************

    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

```
Function Number_of_Words(Text_String As String) As Integer
'Function counts the number of words in a string
'by looking at each character and seeing whether it is a space or not
Number_of_Words = 1
Dim String_Length As Integer
Dim Current_Character As Integer
Dim actualText As String

actualText = Trim(Text_String)
String_Length = Len(actualText)

For Current_Character = 1 To String_Length

    If (Mid(actualText, Current_Character, 1)) = " " Then
        Number_of_Words = Number_of_Words + 1
    End If

Next Current_Character
'MsgBox ("Number_of_Words: " & Number_of_Words)
End Function
```

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671308/best-way-to-define-a-large-vba-string-i-e-heredoc-equivalent

Comment: `If (Number_of_Words(WrdArray(i))) > "20")` can't be right because `Number_of_Words()` returns an int.

Comment: It works fine for length of "wrdArray(I)" < 255. It's giving error only if "wrdArrar( I)" >255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code seems very wrong as it assumes that all sentences are separated by "." and that all words are separated by one " ". I think it should be something like this:

```
Dim s As Range
For Each s In Selection.Sentences
    If s.Words.Count > 20 Then s.Font.Color = wdColorRed
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us *where* the error occurrs.

Doing some research on the net, it seems that the `Find` and `Replace` functionality is limited to strings of 255 characters.

So it seems the error occurrs when calling this functionality, not when passing your string to `Number_of_Words()`.