# Translating SQL query to VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have got SQL query running successfully in Oracle, the code is-

```
Select Sam.SAM_ID, sum( case when Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION between (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') -  14) and 
(next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 7) then 1 else 0 end ) as "Major Defects - 1 week",
 sum( case when Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION between (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') -  28) and (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 7) then 1 else 0 end ) as "Major Defect - 4 week", count(Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION)
From CMS.CMS_SAM_ALL_DATA Sam left join CMS.WATSON_AUDIT_INSPECTION_DT1_VW Aud ON Sam.SAM_ID = Aud.SAM_ID
Where Aud.DEFECT_SEVERITY = 'Major' AND 
Aud.AUD_RESULT = 'Defect' And 
NOT (Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'SPFR Withdrawn' and 
Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'Defect/ Observation Cancelled' and 
Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'Rejected by MIMA' and 
Aud.AUD_RESULT = 'Fixed' and 
Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'SPFR response accepted') and 
Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION IS NOT NULL
Group by Sam.SAM_ID;
```

Now I tried running the above code in macro(VBA) but not able to run macro successfully, Macro code -

```
StrSQL = StrSQL & "Select Sam.SAM_ID,"
 StrSQL = StrSQL & "sum(case when Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION between (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 14) and (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 7) then 1 else 0 end )as ""Major Defects - 1 week"","
    StrSQL = StrSQL & "sum(case when Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION between (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 28) and (next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 7) then 1 else 0 end )as ""Major Defect - 4 week"","
    StrSQL = StrSQL & "count(Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION)as ""Total Open Defects""
    StrSQL = StrSQL & "From CMS.CMS_SAM_ALL_DATA Sam left join CMS.WATSON_AUDIT_INSPECTION_DT1_VW Aud ON Sam.SAM_ID = Aud.SAM_ID"
    StrSQL = StrSQL & "Where Aud.DEFECT_SEVERITY = 'Major' AND Aud.AUD_RESULT = 'Defect' And NOT (Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'SPFR Withdrawn' and Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'Defect/ Observation Cancelled' and Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'Rejected by MIMA' and Aud.AUD_RESULT = 'Fixed' and Aud.AUDIT_OUTCOME = 'SPFR response accepted') and Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION IS NOT NULL, Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION IS NOT NULL, "
    StrSQL = StrSQL & "Group by Sam.SAM_ID;"
```

When I run above code I get an error as -

> FROM Keyword not found where expected

Comment: There's no translation required other than to make a string containing your SQL.  It's unclear what your code sample is showing.  "not able to run macro successfully" is not a really useful description of what happened when you ran your VBA.  Did you get an error?

Comment: how do i write the same whole SQL query in VBA

Comment: By enclosing it in quotes.  Or paste it into a worksheet cell as-is, and have your code read it from there.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671308/best-way-to-define-a-large-vba-string-i-e-heredoc-equivalent

Comment: I have updated the question with error now.

Comment: See the link I posted for how to format your string so it's more readable.

Comment: I think you need to keep the embedded double quotes in your original SQL - you can esacpe them by doubling them up -  `""` inside a VBA string represents a single double quote.

Comment: Run a `Debug.Print StrSQL` and copy-paste the output from the VBE Immediate pane to your query editor - see if it runs and if not it might show you where the problem is.

Comment: is it possible for you to use my VBA script posted above in question and give a shot. I tried the methods advised but was not succesful.

Comment: `and Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION IS NOT NULL, Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION IS NOT NULL, `  should be AND, not a comma in the middle and no comma at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have space beetween from `count(Aud.AUDIT_COMPLETION)From CMS.CMS_SAM_ALL_DATA Sam left`

but take Tim Wiliams advice and split it to new lines. You can also do it like this:

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT "
strSQL = strSQL & "1 "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM dual "
```

Comment: This will produce `SELECT1FROM dual` watch out your spaces!

Answer (score 2):

Use line continuation (_) and double up your quotes to escape them:

```
strSQL = "select a, b as ""My Field"" from " & _
          "tableZ where a = 'blah' and " & _
          "b ='blah' "
```

Comment: I tried the same format as mentioned above, still getting an error as "FROM Keyword not found where expected".

Comment: It would be useful to update your question with the exact VBA you tried.

Comment: I have updated now. One more thing, when I try using &_ after each line it throws up an error as "Invalid Character".

Comment: Is not good to use & _ because this type of line connection has limit of connections...

Comment: @Gadziu - like many other things in programming "good" is not an absolute.  If you have too many lines to use `& _` then do not use it, but if you have that many lines maybe you'd be better off storing your SQL in a worksheet cell where it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Sure, you can :)